# Android studio, stashing or saving open tabs feature?

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea

I use Android studio almost all day - everyday. 
I'm aware that it's a build of IntelliJ.

I also use Git, and I switch between branches hourly.

I was wondering, cause I cannot find a solution searching around:

Is is possible to save open tabs so that when I switch branches I don't lose all my currently open tabs for files that don't exist, plus it would be super nice to see that work-space-view again. when switching to the concurrent branch.

Answer (score -1):

#### For your information:

`.idea` and `*.iml` folder contains all the tab and work space related information of Android Studio Project.

#### Why it is not stored in git branches:

Typically when we create a **.gitignore** file for Android Studio project we include `.idea` folder and `*.iml` in ignore list. That's why switching branches doesn't keeps the changed preferences.

#### What to do:

If you want to track this information for git branches then simply remove this two files from .gitignore list. You can add an extra `#` before **.idea** and ***.iml**

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/
# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

#idea/studio
.idea
*.iml
.DS_Store
captures
```

Comment: Thanks, but switching branches, does this change tabs automatically?

Comment: No, if you ignore the mentioned files (.idea and .iml) then whichever branch you checkout it will not reflect on tabs. It will remain how it was before the checkout.

Comment: I mean, if I switch while the studio is open - is there anyway to restore the current tabs? Or do I have to close and reopen Android studio?

Comment: No you don't need to restart. It will refresh itself.